# Convert string format in razor code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In Razor View how can i convert String type to razor code.I wrote the following Code using the Razor view engine:

```
 @Html.Raw(String.Format("@ViewBag.User.Name{0}", @ViewBag.NameRol))
```

But i am getting the following out put

```
@ViewBag.User.NameManager
```

I need the out put is

**Harry**

Thanks

Comment: Heya, did I manage to answer your question? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, I think you may be stuffing too much into the ViewBag rather than in the view model, where it belongs. But since that's what you're after, I don't think you will be able to get Razor to evaluate something that it itself emitted as raw.

You could, however, use a Dictionary in the ViewBag. Something like this

```
// controller action:
var users = new Dictionary<string, string>();
users.Add("Manager", "Harry");
users.Add("Employee", "John");

ViewBag.Role = "Manager";
ViewBag.Users = users;


// view:
@ViewBag.Users[ViewBag.Role]
```